# Improve GraphDb preformances when using both geo and Lucene

Tags: performance, sparql, graphdb

Im a working with GraphDb, free edition untill full validation.
When selecting using the geo function

```
?s  omgeo:nearby(lat long dist).
```

I get an answer in less 0.5 second

And same result using the full text search

```
?search a luc-index:LuceneFTS ;
luc:query 'SomeText';
luc:entities ?s.
```

But when combining both queries

```
?s  omgeo:nearby(lat long dist).
?search a luc-index:LuceneFTS ;
luc:query 'SomeText';
luc:entities ?s.
```

GraphDb is stuck or takes more than 20 seconds to answer.
I tried to inverse places of queries, embed one in a sub select

```
select { xxxx {select {yyy} } }
```

but all attempts give the same result.
With Oracle you cat get the plan of selections, I guess there is not such tool with GraphDb. But is there at least tricks to improve performances and make them acceptable?

Comment: you can see the query plan in GraphDB: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/explain-plan.html#:~:text=GraphDB's%20Explain%20Plan%20is%20a,leading%20to%20better%20execution%20performance.

Comment: Very basic plan and it seems each group is treated independently from others and then triples being in all results groups are returned.